# MongoDB - aggregation group sum on 2 levels of a aub-array and subdocument

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is my issue. I checked with a lot of other MongoDB questions on the site, but none matches my condition below.

I have a MongoDB embedded document structure that looks like this: -

```
{
    company : "ABC",
    year : 2010,
    Project : [{
            Domain : "Telecom",
            Client: [{"Name": "Ponderfone","size":25},{"Name": "Skytel","size":35},{"Name": "ChinaTel","size":10}]
        }, {
            Domain : "Retail",
            Client: [{"Name": "Gatemart","size":95},{"Name": "Clearway","size":40}]         
        }, {
            Domain : "Finance",
            Client: [{"Name": "MFCI","size":20},{"Name": "FCCI","size":20},{"Name": "MobiBank","size":35}]              
        }
    ]
}
{
    company : "ABC",
    year : 2011,
    Project : [{
            Domain : "Telecom",
            Client: [{"Name": "Ponderfone","size":50},{"Name": "Skytel","size":30},{"Name": "ChinaWay","size":30}]
        }, {
            Domain : "Retail",
            Client: [{"Name": "Gatemart","size":120},{"Name": "Shadowfax","size":15}]           
        }, {
            Domain : "Finance",
            Client: [{"Name": "Reuben Analysts","size":15},{"Name": "FCCI","size":10},{"Name": "MobiBank","size":35}]               
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem here is that I am trying to aggregate a column in the innermost document, which is embedded 2 levels inside: -
"Project.Client.Size"

I am trying to sum this column for a particular domain (if you see the JSON)

```
db.projects.aggregate(
{ $match: {"year" : 2010,"company" :"ABC"}},
{ $unwind: "$Project" },
{ $match: { $or: [{"Project.Domain" : /Telecom/},{"Project.Domain" :/Retail/}]}},
{ $group: { "_id": {company: "$company", year: "$year", domain: "$Project.Domain"},
headcount: { "$sum":" $Project.Client.size" }}
})
```

The problem with this code is that it is returning the results with the headcount marked to 0.

```
{ "_id" : { "company" : "ABC", "year" : 2010, "domain" : "Retail" }, "headcount"
 : 0 }
{ "_id" : { "company" : "ABC", "year" : 2010, "domain" : "Telecom" }, "headcount
" : 0 }
```

Headcount should be (25+35+10) 70 for Telecom, year 2010 and company ABC
Headcount should be (95+40) 135 for Retail, year 2010 and company ABC

Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** pipeline step after the last **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** filter in your pipeline. This is necessary to denormalize the `Client` array so that you can access its properties for aggregation in the next **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline. Thus your final pipeline should follow this pattern:

---

```
db.projects.aggregate([
    { "$match": {"year": 2010, "company": "ABC"} },
    { "$unwind": "$Project" },
    { "$match": { "$or": [{"Project.Domain": /Telecom/},{"Project.Domain": /Retail/}] } },
    { "$unwind": "$Project.Client" },
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": {
                "company": "$company", 
                "year": "$year", 
                "domain": "$Project.Domain"
            },
            "headcount": { "$sum": "$Project.Client.size" }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Perfect .. Thanks a tonne .. I would have taken eons to figure this one out !!